# Displace modifier ignores texture coords

Tags: modifiers, uv, displacement

I want to add some details to a cylindrical model in Blender. The model already has UV coordinates and a texture applied to it (see left image).

Now I want to use that same texture and UV coordinates to add the details via displacement. After adding the Displace modifier, details are added all over the mesh in a weird way (see right image). I would have expected to see bumps only where the white parts are in my texture (i.e. NOT at the top of my mesh).

I already tried all possible settings for "Coordinates" (e.g. Local, Global, Object, UV...), but none gives the expected result.

[image]

Comment: Your goal is to add height to your model? What exactly is your goal? Because If you want for black parts of the texture to be higher than white? In that case don't use Displace modifier, displace modifier will give you random surface retopology based on that texture... if you want to control it precisely and give it only holes in white spots, use shader nodes with texture, bump node and normal

Comment: My goal is to "extrude" the white spots a little, to give the model a rough/grippy surface. I thought the displace modifier was exactly the right tool for this. Bumpmaps are not what I'm after since I need an actual rough 3D surface.

Answer (score 0):

To extend my comment, you can use this simple setup... instead of the Voronoi Texture use your own grid texture. ColorRamp will help you to make holes only where white is.
[image]

It basically does what you want, white and black, one will be deeper and one will be higher

Like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: But this won't affect the actual mesh, which is what I'm after.

Comment: then it is not possible like this because you first need that topology that you want to reshape, how does that object look in edit mode? If it is a low poly model, technically you can make high poly one from it and then displace it, but that will make a pretty dense object with millions of vertices to make it look right, a better solution would be to make it from scratch with this topology in mind and make it low topology instead (but I don't know what you need it for, short answer - if you don't care about optimization and vert number, just subdivide it a lot and do it again